# Disable breaktime in Multi resource view in full calendar and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am doing resource allocation on certain events. I am using resource view, so all resources on one page only.

I am using jQuery full calendar with php. The Fullcalendar is working functionally alright. but I want to do some formatting and want to make some restriction.

- I want to enable only working hours for the resource. like some resource is working 9 to 5 with break from 1:00 to 2:00 pm. some resource from 4:00 tp 10:00 with break from 7:00 to 8:00 pm. Means i want to mark those time when resource is not available or already busy.

I have done different colors for different events but client wants like this.

Please any one help me how to change in fullcalendar jquery or my code >

How can i achieve this changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it by changing in fullcalendar jquery.

I have changed their jquery code of building fullcalendar. and its done in fullcalendar resource view according to particular resource's roster.